# How to read large CSV files

Tags: csv, go

What is the best way to read large CSV files, at the moment I am reading one record at a time rather than using `ReadAll()`.

```
reader := csv.NewReader(csvFile)
reader.FieldsPerRecord = -1

for {
    // read just one record at a time
    record, err := reader.Read()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        checkErr(err)
        return
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this to save memory?

I am writing each record/row to a database by sending an array over GRPC to a separate service.

Comment: That depends on what you're doing with the data. Is part of a row something you can act on? Usually when processing a CSV the smallest viable unit of work is one row.

Comment: Seems right. If you end up with your program bogging down the system or dying due to memory use, or something like that, post a question with more context of what you're doing and what you see happening.

Comment: I am writing each record/row to a database by sending an array over GRPC to a separate service.

Comment: What qualifies as "best" or "better" depends on a lot of factors, several of them even external to code. Never start thinking about "better", "improve" or that like until you are sure about the quality characteristics you are after.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is one option you can use to improve it.
It is possible to allow reader to reuse a slice that is returned by it on each `Read` method call.
To do it you need to set `reader.ReuseRecord = true`.
But be careful, because the returned slice may be changed after the next call of `Read`!